# Angular children routes in Lazy Loaded module don't completely work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using Angular 2.3.1

I having trouble navigating to children routes in a lazy loaded module. What is very odd to me is that 2 of 3 children routes are working perfect. But when I tried to add a 3rd route, it's that particular route that doesn't seem work.

Because some routes are working, you would think it's a problem with the component that's associated with the ill fated route...but I don't believe this is the case...The component is just bare bones class & template. There's nothing in it:

Here is my **Root App Routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: HomePageComponent},
  {
    path: 'facilities',
    loadChildren: './search-page/search-page.module#SearchPageModule'
  },
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
```

Here is my **module routing**, where I'm creating children routes.

```
const searchPageRoutes : Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SearchPageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path:'search', // ROUTE WORKS
                component: SearchResultsComponent,
                canActivate: [FacilitiesGuard]
            },
            {
                path: ':id', // ROUTE WORKS
                component: FacilityDetailComponent,
                resolve: {facility:  FacilityDataResolver }
            },
            {
                path: 'saved', // ROUTE NOT WORKING
                component: FacilitiesListComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(searchPageRoutes)
    ],
    exports:[
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

**ERROR**
The error I'm getting is the same error that occurs if I remove the route all together...as if the route is not even being defined. Angular tries to make a backend API call with the route:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/facilities/saved (500) Internal server Error
```

This error occurs because this route doesn't exist in the API.

What am I doing wrong or why is the 'saved' route not being found by angular?

Comment: Knowing that route order in the config is important, have you tried moving the `saved` route above the `:id` route to see what the result might be? Wait... are you having issues with client-side (Angular) routing, or server-side (API) routing?

Comment: @R.Richards Wait what?! Why does that work. Can you expound on that?

Comment: Does it work? I was thinking the order was an issue since the route needing a parameter (id) was before the saved route. Maybe the router doesn't like that. I have had my share of issues with routing, so it was a bit of a guess. I will ask again: is this an issue with client or server routing? Because my suggestion doesn't apply if this is a server route issue. We would need to see your server route config then.

Comment: @R.Richards your suggestion did work. Thank you...And to clear up the confusion of client vs. server routing...this was all on the client. I'm still perplexed on why your suggestion work though.

Comment: All I can say that order is a factor with Angular routes. The router thinks that anything trying to go to the `saved` route was stopped at the `:id` route, because the router is thinking that the term "saved" was just another parameter be passed to it. Does that help at all?

Comment: @R.Richards Gotcha...that makes more sense. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Dropped this into an answer in case other run across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on comment conversation:

The issue here is the order of the routes in the configuration.

This:

```
{
    path: ':id', // ROUTE WORKS
    component: FacilityDetailComponent,
    resolve: {facility:  FacilityDataResolver }
},
{
    path: 'saved', // ROUTE NOT WORKING
    component: FacilitiesListComponent
}
```

Needs to be this:

```
{
    path: 'saved', // ROUTE WORKING NOW!
    component: FacilitiesListComponent
},
{
    path: ':id', // ROUTE STILL WORKS
    component: FacilityDetailComponent,
    resolve: {facility:  FacilityDataResolver }
}
```

Essentially, the router thinks that anything trying to go to the `saved` route was stopped at the `:id` route, because the router is thinking that the term "saved" was just another parameter be passed to it.